# How to translate these photoshop details in to box-shadow

Tags: html, css

I have been developing an application in which there are some designs designed on Photoshop

```
opacity - 40%
ditance - 1px
size - 2px
angle - 90
```

Can someone help me in converting them in to box-shadow?

Comment: Try one of hundreds of `box-shadow` generators: http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow, http://css3gen.com/box-shadow/,  http://css3generator.com/ ...

Comment: W3C has a good explanaition of box-shadows: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#box-shadow Note: they don't use the Photoshop terms. IIRC there is a Compass mixin that can consume the Photoshop values and produce an appropriate box-shadow.

Comment: Found one: https://github.com/heygrady/compass-photoshop-drop-shadow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look

```
 .class {
     box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);

 }
```

Explanation:

the first to arguments define position. Shadow will now appear right and bottom.

The second argument provides the distance.

rgba gives you an rgb color with opacity. (Provided between 0 and 1).

Read up here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow.